# generate jquery list from array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a brand list with about 2000 items, my problem is I want to generate a list of commands In jquery using this format dynamically.

```
 $("select[name='brand']").change(function () {
     $("#brand1,#brand2").hide();
     if ($(this).val() == "brand1") { $("#brand1").show(); } 
     else if ($(this).val() == "brand2") { $("#brand2").show(); }
       and so on...
 });
```

the list of brands is located in MySQL which I brought into an array called

> allBrands[] in php

so if the brands update in the MySQL, it will also update in the jquery script.

Obviously I can manually type in each brand, but i'm worried about when I update the database for newer brands etc..

Edit: that being said, if I can do a MySQL call in jquery and get the list of brands that way, that would also work. Brand1, brand2 = examples, names are random based on brand

Answer (score 1):

If the data is ordered in the same way your 2 examples suggest you could try this:

```
$("select[name='brand']").change(function () {
     $("[id^=brand]").hide();  // all id's starting with the word "brand"
     $("#" + this.value).show(); // if the value is the same as the id you want to target
 });
```

About the jQuery `^=`, read [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

If the brands do not start with the word brand you can use `$(".brands").hide();`, and use the rest as I posted.

Comment: sorry, I don't know jquery that well, can you explain how your new code works? what does id^ do? the data in MySQL is in a column called brands, the brand1 brand2 is an example.

Comment: @AlbertD, just added a link to more info on that selector. Also and dispite my __many__ reservations about w3schools, here is a link with many different selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: where do you get this.value from? how do you generate the list in jquery of all the brands, I can't use the first example cause the brands are not numbered they are random names of brands, but thanks for the link to help me understand it..

Comment: @AlbertD, `this.value` is the selected value of the select. So, when the select changed `this.value` is the new selected value.